# Uso de la función input lanza error de definición usando el entorno Canopy

Tags: python

Descargue el programa Canopy para ocupar python (en Mac) y todo funcionaba bien hasta que al tratar ingresar una cadena mediante la función `input`, me manda mensaje de error del tipo:

> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

No se que hacer, ¿que podrá ser?. Para una línea muy sencilla como, `nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre: ")` le escribo un nombre cualquiera (no numérico), pero salta el error diciendo que ese nombre no está definido.

Este es mi código:

```
Diez=10
Jota=11
Queen=12
Kaiser=13
c="corazones"
d="diamantes"
p="pica"
t="trebol"
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"Diez","Jota","Queen","Kaiser"]
b=[c,d,p,t]
def Cartas():
    ans = []
    for element in a:
        (str(element)+" de "+str(c))
        ans.append(str(element)+" de "+str(c))
        (str(element)+" de "+str(d))
        ans.append(str(element)+" de "+str(d))
        (str(element)+" de "+str(p))
        ans.append(str(element)+" de "+str(p))
        (str(element)+" de "+str(t))
        ans.append(str(element)+" de "+str(t))
    return ans
mazo = Cartas()
n=str(input("numero jugadores:  "))
if (int(n)<2 or int(n)>52):
    print("escribe otro numero entre 2 y 52")
else:
    nmbrs = []
    i=1
    while (i<int(n)+1):
        nombre_jug=str(input("nombre jugador "+str(i)+":"))
        i+=1
        nmbrs.append(nombre_jug)
    print(nmbrs)
import random
random.shuffle(mazo)
carta_x_jugador=len(mazo)//int(n)
cartas_sobran=len(mazo)%int(n)
nuevo_mazo=mazo[int(cartas_sobran):]
```

En la parte donde me pide el nombre de los jugadores:

```
nombre_jug=str(input("nombre jugador "+str(i)+":"))
```

solo me deja ingresar números.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código que te genera el error?

Comment: n=str(input("numero jugadores:  "))
if (int(n)<2 or int(n)>52):
    print("escribe otro numero entre 2 y 52")
else:
    nmbrs = []
    i=1
    while (i<int(n)+1):
        nombre_jug=str(input("nombre jugador "+str(i)+":"))
        i+=1
        nmbrs.append(nombre_jug)
    print(nmbrs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es prácticamnte seguro que estas usando Python 2.x e intentas usar sintaxis propia de Python 3. Puedes mirar el intérprete que usas en Canopy mediante:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

En Python 2.x existen dos funciones para permitir la entrada de información desde la terminal:

- `raw_input`: retorna la cadena ingresada en crudo, es decir, siempre retorna texto.
- `input`: en su lugar espera que se le pasen expresiones Python válidas. Es decir, solo se le puede pasar código Python y la función lo evalua y procesa como tal.

Cuando usas `input` y le pasas un número lo evalua correctamente ya que un entero es una expresión Python válida. Tu puedes poner 2 en el intérprete interactivo lo acepta perfectamente. Cuando introduces una cadena de la forma `Hola` la función `input` lo intenta evaluar como código python, es decir, busca una función, variable o clase llamada de este modo en el namespace actual, como no existe retorna con un error diciendo que no está definida.

Para que `input` evalue algo como una cadena debes pasarle eso, una cadena. Es decir, debes pasarle el texto entre comillas:

```
>>> nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
>>> 'Hola'
```

De todas formas el uso de `input` en Python 2 está desaconsejado en la gran mayoría de casos. Para lo que quieres usa `raw_input`:

```
nombre_jug= raw_input("nombre jugador "+str(i)+":"))
```

En Python 3 `raw_input` no existe (su función la hace `eval`) e `input` equivale a `raw_input` en Python 2.

Puedes mirarte esta pregunta para más información:

[Duda con raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38288/duda-con-raw-input)

Un ejemplo de lo explicado usando el intérprete interacivo de python 2.7:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>>
>>> nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
Ingrese el nombre: 'hola'
>>> nombre
'hola'
>>>
>>> nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
Ingrese el nombre: hola

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    nombre= input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hola' is not defined
>>>
>>> nombre= raw_input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
Ingrese el nombre: hola
>>> nombre
'hola'
>>>
>>> num= int(raw_input("Ingrese un entero: "))
Ingrese un entero: 12
>>> num
12
>>>
>>> 1245
1245
>>>
>>> hola

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    hola
NameError: name 'hola' is not defined
>>>
>>> 'hola'
'hola'
```

Comment: muchas gracias, de verdad me salvaste