# Error al ingresar datos con input()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Este es mi código, el cual ejecuto en Python 2.7.13:

```
print "hola"
hiola = input()
if hiola == salsa:
    print "hola"
```

Y el error que me lanza es el siguiente:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Programacion\Python\hola.py", line 2, in <module>
>     hiola = input()
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'salsa' is not defined
> ```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo que intentes redactar algo tus preguntas para hacerlas más claras. Por otro lado debes formatear el código adecuadamente, para ello copias tu código en el editor de la pregunta, lo seleccionas y pulsas el botón `{}` del editor, o bién Ctrl+k. Por ser tu primera vez en el sitio he editado tu pregunta lo más adecuadamente que he podido, pero recuerdalo para otras ocasiones. Saludos.

Comment: gracias, lo recordare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `input` bajo python 2.7 como se haría en Python 3. [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) espera código Python válido el cual evalúa, si ingresas `hola` u otra cadena sin usar comillas (`"hola"`), interpreta que es un identificador, como una variable, y al no estar definida en el espacio de nombres, lanza la excepción mostrada.

Para hacer lo que quieres en Python 2.x debes usar [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) que retorna siempre una cadena:

```
print "hola"
hiola = raw_input()
if hiola == 'salsa':
    print "hola"
```

Por otro lado no entrecomillas `salsa`, si es una variable debes definirla antes, por ejemplo:

```
salsa = 'hola'
```

si `salsa` no es una variable y es una cadena literal debes ponerla entre comilla:

```
if hiola == 'salsa':
```

Para ver las diferencias entre `input` y `raw_input` (y las diferencias al respecto entre Python 3 y Python 2) puedes mirarte esta pregunta:

- [Diferencia entre input() y raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089)

Comment: ok, ahora pongo. hola = raw_input("cual es la contraseña: ")
if hola == 'salsa':
 print "bienvenido"
y me dice. SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '. on line 1

Comment: @SENIORofPRESTON354 la 'ñ' no es un carácter ASCII (como las tildes y demás).  Python 2.x decodifica el código usando ASCII por defecto, de ahí el problema: añade la línea `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` como primera o segunda línea en tu script para especificar la codificación que se debe usar al intérprete y guarda tu .py con codificación utf-8 si es que tu editor no lo hace ya. Si no necesitas usar por fuerza mayor Python 2 usa Python 3 en su lugar, te evitarás muchos de estos problemas.

Comment: entonces como pongo la ñ, o no se puede? pd. ya funciono

Comment: @SENIORofPRESTON354, entonces, ¿solucionado?

Comment: como puedo poner la 'ñ'

Comment: y como borrar la pantalla?

Comment: Para eso es lo de  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  en la primera línea del script. Esto indica al intérprete que debe decodificar el archivo usando utf-8 que si admite la ñ. Simplemente pon tu código con la ñ, añades esta línea como **primera o segunda línea** a tu script y guardas el .py con codificación utf-8.