# name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python

Es una historia donde tu ingresas los nombres pero no los esta reconociendo
sale `NameError: name '' is not defined`

Al parecer no reconoce el string.

```
girldescription = " " 
boydescription = " " 
walkdescription = " " 
girlname = " "
boyname = " "
animal = " "
gift = " " 
answer = " "


girlname = input("Enter a girl's name: ")
boyname = input("Enter a boy's name: " )
animal = input("Name a type of animal: " )
gift = input("Name something you find in the bathroom: ")
girldescription = input("Enter a description of a flower: ")
boydescription = input("Enter a description of a car: ")
walkdescription = input("Enter a description of how you might dance: " )
answer = input("What would you say to someone who gave you a cow: ")



print ("Once upon a time,")
print("there was a girl named " + girlname.capitalize() + ".")
print("One day, " + girlname.capitalize() + " was walking " + walkdescription.lower() + " down the street.")
print("Then she met a " + boydescription.lower() + " boy named " + boyname.capitalize() + ".")
print("He said, 'You are really " + girldescription.lower() + "!'")
print("She said '" + answer.capitalize() + ", " + boyname.capitalize() + ".'")
print("Then they both rode away on a " + animal.lower() + " and lived happily ever after.")
```

Comment: ¿Usas Python 2 por casualidad? Ese código es correcto para Python  3, no para Python 2 a causa de la función `input`: [Error al ingresar datos con input en python-2-7-13](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70839/error-al-ingresar-datos-con-input-en-python-2-7-13). Puedes mirarte también [Duda con raw_input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089). En caso contrario indica en qué linea y con que entrada da error. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado con raw_input. Pensé que tenía Python 3

Comment: Hola FerJPi, bienvenido a [es.so]. Si estas aprendiendo te aconsejo usar Python 3, Python 2 dejará de tener soporte en 2020, en mi opinión y con vistas a futuro es mejor aprender o desarrollar nuevas aplicaciones en Python 3 si no existen razones de peso para hacerlo en Python 2.7.  Si  tu problema está resuelto voy a votar para cerrar la pregunta como duplicado. Un saludo.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que pasa es que `input` captura los datos pero antes los interpreta es decir esta intentando algo como

```
nombre = CARLOS
```

Y te returno el error

```
name "CARLOS" is not defined
```

así que para que funcione tu código te tocaría ingresar los valores en consola, Si por ejemplo corres tu código y en lugar de teclear `CARLOS` tecleas `"CARLOS"` , no te dará error.

Por esta razón lo mejor sería usar `raw_input` in no `input` , [acá puedes consultar mas información](https://www.python-course.eu/input.php)

ejemplo:

```
Enter a girl's name: "Andrea"
```

o si no cambiar a `raw_input` ya puedes ingresarlo normalmente, otra cosa no necesitas definir las variables como vacías al inicio.

```
girlname = raw_input("Enter a girl's name: ")
boyname = raw_input("Enter a boy's name: " )
animal = raw_input("Name a type of animal: " )
gift = raw_input("Name something you find in the bathroom: ")
girldescription = raw_input("Enter a description of a flower: ")
boydescription = raw_input("Enter a description of a car: ")
walkdescription = raw_input("Enter a description of how you might dance: " )
answer = raw_input("What would you say to someone who gave you a cow: ")



print ("Once upon a time,")
print("there was a girl named " + girlname.capitalize() + ".")
print("One day, " + girlname.capitalize() + " was walking " + walkdescription.lower() + " down the street.")
print("Then she met a " + boydescription.lower() + " boy named " + boyname.capitalize() + ".")
print("He said, 'You are really " + girldescription.lower() + "!'")
print("She said '" + answer.capitalize() + ", " + boyname.capitalize() + ".'")
```

Saludos

Comment: Esto es en python2.7, ya que en python3 si se puede usar `input` para strings