# ¿Cómo añadir información a un fichero en Python?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def Agregar():
    nuevoLibro = input("Introduzca el nombre del libro: \n") #Aquí es donde me lanza el error: NameError: name 'Ejemplo' is not defined
    Escritor = open("Libros.txt", "a")
    Escritor.write(nuevoLibro)
    Escritor.close()
    print("Se ha añadido con éxito")

def Ver():
    Escritor = open("Libros.txt", "r")
    Contenido = Escritor.read()
    print(Contenido)
    Escritor.close()

def Borrar():
    Vacio = ""
    Escritor = open("Libros.txt", "w")
    Escritor.write(Vacio)
    Escritor.close()
    print("Se borró toda la biblioteca")

def Opciones():
    try:
        Opcion = int(input("¿Qué quieres hacer? Seleccione un número \n 1) Agregar | 2) Ver | 3) Borrar | 4) Salir \n"))
    except Exception as e:
        raise e #Aquí estoy tratando de que si el usuario introduce una letra lance un mensaje que le indique que debe escribir un número
    if (Opcion == 1):
        Agregar()
    elif (Opcion == 2):
        Ver()
    elif (Opcion == 3):
        Borrar()
    elif (Opcion == 4):
        print("¡Adios!")
        exit()
    else: 
        print("\n\nDebe seleccionar una opción valida\n\n")
        Opciones()

Opciones()
```

Estoy tratando de hacer una biblioteca, mi idea es añadir, mostrar, editar,y borrar datos de la misma, pero cuando lo trato de añadir me salta un error en la línea 4 que dice `NameError: name 'Ejemplo' is not defined`, además no entiendo (o no sé si se podrá) editar una línea específica para así ir actualizando información en vez de borrarlo todo y volverlo a hacer, que es lo que está ocurriendo aquí...

Comment: ¿Usas python 2.x por casualidad?

Comment: Sí, uso Python 2.7 pero también tengo el 3

Comment: Mirate https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38288/duda-con-raw-input. No uses **nunca** `input` para capturar entradas de usuario Python 2.x sin tener una buena razón, usa `raw_input`. Con `input` intenta interpretar el texto introducido como código Python, como `Ejemplo` no es una variable/clase/función definida en tu espacio de nombres lanza el error. Si tienes Python 3 usa Python 3, ese código es perfectamente válido para Python 3. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo :) Lo probé con python3 main.py y funcionó.

Comment: Daniel si puedes usar Python 3 deja Python 2. La rama 2 va a dejar de tener soporte en 2020 y no va a recibir nuevas actualizaciones importantes (Python 2.7 es la última versión). Si estás aprendiendo no tiene sentido usar Python 2, además de complicarte la vida en algunos aspectos, sobretodo con lo referido a la codificación. Saludos

Comment: Con respecto a lo de editar el archivo, ¿no hay alguna manera de editar el archivo? Para que por ejemplo te salga nano o quizá que introduzcas el número de la línea que quieres editar.

Comment: Puedes usar [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) para que te abra cualquier editor que tengas en tu sistema si lo deseas, también podrias usar `Tkinter` y abrir un `Text` Widget y editarlo en él. En cuanto a editar una linea usando su número es también posible, lo más simple es cargar todas las líneas en una lista (usa `readlines()`), usas los índices para obtener la línea que quieras, la modificas y sobreescribes el archivo de nuevo usando las líneas de la lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre tu problema con la función `input`, en Python 2 ejecutar esa línea es equivalente a usar una mezcla entre [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) con [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

```
>>> input("Introduzca el nombre del libro: \n") 
Introduzca el nombre del libro: 
Ejemplo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Ejemplo' is not defined

>>> help(input)
Help on built-in function input in module __builtin__:

input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Por lo tanto, `eval()` está tratando de encontrar una variable llamada `Ejemplo` pero esta no ha sido definida. De ahí el error de tipo `NameError`.

Lo que necesitas es cambiar tu sentencia por `raw_input()`:

```
>>> nuevoLibro = raw_input("Introduzca el nombre del libro: \n")
Introduzca el nombre del libro: 
Ejemplo
>>> nuevoLibro
'Ejemplo'
```

Otras recomendaciones:

- Toma el consejo de @FJSevilla y comienza a migrar hacia Python 3.
- Para borrar el contenido de un archivo puedes usar `truncate()`:

  ```
  def Borrar():
      archivo = open("Libros.txt", "r+")
      archivo.truncate()
      archivo.close()
      print "Se borró toda la biblioteca"
  ```

  Observa que estoy abriendo el archivo con `r+` ya que esto no funciona si abres el archivo en modo de "solo lectura".