# Duda sobre método write

Tags: python, pyserial

Una pregunta muy sencilla, ¿si en `write` quiero escribir dos cosas como debo hacerlo?

Un ejemplo:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    entrada = input("Introduce el angulo: ")
    ser.write(str(entrada))
```

¿Qué debo hacer aquí para que el `write` escriba la `entrada` y luego un *1* detrás de esta y que, si yo en la `entrada` escribo *90*, el `write` envie *901*?

Comment: Si te he entendido solo concatena: `ser.write((str(entrada) + "1").encode())` o usa str.format: `ser.write("{}1".format(entrada).encode())`. Una observación, si usas Python 2  usa `raw_input`, si usas Python 3   usa `input`. Ambas retornan una cadena. basta con hacer luego:`ser.write(entrada + "1")...` Evita`input` en Python 2  para entradas de usuario sin filtrar , es muy peligroso. Mirate [Duda con raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38288/duda-con-raw-input).

Comment: @FJSevilla muchas gracias. El problema es que no ha salido como me esperaba. Quería hacer esto para evitarme tener que poner el 1 pero mi servo no se mueve.

Comment: ¿Que error te da?¿Por qué no funciona exactamente?¿Usas Python 2 o Python 3?

Comment: @FJSevilla Ningún error. Escribo el angulo y el servomotor no se mueve. Eso si, si escribo el angulo con el 1 al final como hacia antes por una extraña razón no se mueve donde que le corresponde.

Comment: @FJSevilla perdón pero ahora si que me funciona. No se que había hecho mal antes.  Falsa alarma. Ya he puesto lo de raw_input. Ahora solo me falta hacer una web que me permita mover los servos. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente debes concatenar ambas cadenas:

```
ser.write((str(entrada) + "1").encode())
```

O usando `str.format()`:

```
ser.write("{}1".format(entrada).encode())
```

En Python  >= 3.6 se pueden usar literales de cadena formateados:

```
ser.write(f"{entrada}1".encode())
```

Es importante asegurarse que a `write` se le pasan bytes y no una cadena codificada u otro tipo de dato (por eso el uso de `encode`).  En Python 2, si estamos seguros de que el resultado es de tipo `str` no hace falta. Este código es válido para Python 2 y Python 3.

Por otro lado, usar `input` en Python 2 para entradas de usuario sin filtrar es muy peligroso dado que ejecuta todo código válido introducido. En su lugar se debe usar `raw_input` que, al igual que `input` en Python 3, retorna un objeto `str`. Ver [Duda con raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089) para más información.