# ¿Por que no me funciona el raw_input()?

Tags: python, shell, entrada

En Python 3.6.2 en mi Shell pongo:

```
print ("Hola mundo")
raw_input()
```

Lo ejecuto y me manda este error:

> ```
> multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
> ```

Comment: Sonia bienvenida a [es.so]. Mirate la pregunta [Duda con raw_input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089) que expone la misma duda. Básicamente `raw_input` es propia de Python 2.x y no existe en Python 3.x, donde su equivalente es `input`. El equivalente a `input` en Python 2 es `eval` en Python 3. Mírate mi respuesta a la pregunta anterior donde se explica mejor. El error en realidad es porque en la shell solo puedes ejecutar un estamento cada vez, `print ("Hola mundo")`  y pulsas `enter` y luego `input()` y pulsas `enter` no ambas copiadas  y `enter`... Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa que en python 3.x esa función ya no tiene elmismo nombre.
Ahora se utiliza solamente "input".
Ejemplo:

> numero = input("Introduzca un número: ")

Comment: Muchas gracias!
fue solucionado

Comment: @SoniaAragon si fue solucionado recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta. Es el *check* bajo la puntuacion de la respuesta. Pero considera mirar el enlace que te pusieron en los comentarios de tu pregutna ya que esta es un duplicado. Un saludo