# Error con el valor del input. Al introducir el valor debo poner la letra en ' sino no me lo reconoce

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este es el código en cuestión:

```py
import sys

clients = ['luisa', 'juan']

def create_client(client_name):
    global clients

    if client_name not in clients :
        clients.append(client_name)
    else:
        print ('Client already is in the client\'s list')

def list_clients():
    for idx, client in enumerate(clients):
        print ('{} : {}'.format(idx, client))


def updated_client(client_name, updated_client_name):
    global clients

    if client_name in clients :
        index = clients.index(client_name)
        clients[index] = updated_name
    else:
        print ('Client is no it client\'s list')


def delete_client(client_name):
    global clients

    if client_name in clients:
        clients.remove(client_name)
    else:
        print('Client is not in client\'s list')

def search_client(client_name):

    for client in clients:
        if client != client_name:
            continue
        else:
            return True


def _print_welcome():
    print ('WELCOME TO PLATZI VENTAS')
    print ('*' * 50)
    print ('What would you like to do today ? ')
    print ('[C]reate client')
    print ('[L]ist client')
    print ('[U]pdated client')
    print ('[D]elete client')
    print ('[S]earch client')


def _get_client_name ():
    client_name = None

    while not client_name:
        client_name = str.lower(input('What is the client name ? '))

        if client_name == 'exit':
            client_name = None
            break

    if not client_name:
            sys.exit()

    return client_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _print_welcome()

    command = input('Select option')
    command = command.upper()


    if command == 'C':
        client_name = _get_client_name()
        create_client(client_name)
        list_clients()
    elif command == 'L':
        list_clients()
    elif command == 'U':
        client_name = _get_client_name()
        updated_name = str.lower(input ('What is the updated client name ? '))
        updated_client(client_name, updated_name)
        list_clients()
    elif command == 'D':
        client_name = _get_client_name()
        delete_client(client_name)
        list_clients()
    elif command == 'S':
        client_name = _get_client_name()
        found = search_client(client_name)

        if found:
            print('The client is in the client\'s list')
        else:
            print('The client: {} is not in our client\'s list'.format(client_name))

    else:
        print ('Invalid command')
```

Y al ejecutarlo. Este es el error que me da:

```
WELCOME TO PLATZI VENTAS
**************************************************
What would you like to do today ? 
[C]reate client
[L]ist client
[U]pdated client
[D]elete client
[S]earch client
Select optionC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 74, in <module>
    command = input('Select option')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

Sin embargo si en lugar de añadir una solamente la letra pongo la letra + comillas. Sí que me reconoce la letra:

```
WELCOME TO PLATZI VENTAS
**************************************************
What would you like to do today ? 
[C]reate client
[L]ist client
[U]pdated client
[D]elete client
[S]earch client
Select option'C'
What is the client name ?
```

Lo mismo me pasa con todos los demás inputs del programa.
No sé si es un problema a la hora de declarar el input que debo especificar que es un String. Aunque según he leído esto debería hacerlo ya por defecto.

O es un problema a la hora de hacer las declaraciones de los if, elif y else. Que no reconocen el String o que al comparar debo especificar que el elemento con el que lo estoy comparando es un String.

Ayuda URGENTE please!!

Comment: Hola BarckCode, ¿Seguro que no **ejecutas el código con Python 2** y no con Python 3 como indica la etiqueta de la pregunta? Mirate [Diferencia entre input() y raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón al ejecutar en consola: python3 main.py Sí que me ejecuta bien el programa.
Ahora debo averiguar como hacer que mi consola ejecute Python 3 por defecto solo poniendo Python :(
Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo usas?

Comment: macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Mírate esto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5846167/7131499, a ver si te ayuda. Voy a votar por cerrar la pregunta, dado que no es problema del código, solo que lo ejecutabas con el intérprete equivocado :). Si tienes algún otro problema, o con lo de cambiar el intérprete por defecto no dudes en preguntar. Un saludo.

Comment: Sí, perfecto muchísimas gracias nuevamente!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir una conversión a string en la entrada del input

```py
    command = str(input('Select option'))
    command = command.upper()
```