# Problema Bàsico: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, variables

Esto es una parte simplificada del programa original:

Como puedo hacer de tal manera que escribiendo el valor `L1` o `L2` o `Lx`, el `input` interprete què es un valor numérico, y m1 tome el valor 1, 2,... I después darme la media?

```
L1=1
L2=2
L3=3

# (m1 = MIEMBRO1)

m1=input("Inserte nivel del primer miebro: ") #AQUI ESCRIBE UNO DE LOS VALORES L1, L2 O L3, y EL OUTPUT DEVUELVE 1, 2 O 3

m2=input("Inserte nivel del segundo miebro: ") #AQUI ESCRIBE UNO DE LOS VALORES P1, P2 O P3, y EL OUTPUT DEVUELVE 1, 2 O 3

media_nivel= (m1+m2)/2

print(media_nivel)
```

Pero al ejecutar y devolver en el input L1 o L2

```
Insert level of the first member: L1
Insert level of the second member: L2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OFF.py", line 9, in <module>
    level_average= (m1+m2)/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

***Repl Closed***
```

PD: Se qué es un programa muy sencillo, recién he empezado con python y me surgen dudas (bastante básicas). Agradezco toda ayuda.

Comment: Una duda, ¿intentas que al ingresar la cadena "L2" la variable `m1` tome el valor de `2`? Porque eso es otro problema diferente...

Comment: Exactamente, es lo que intento hacer. Desconozco la forma para que tome el valor 2 o 1.

Answer (score 3):

La función`input` en Python 3.x retorna siempre una cadena (`str`), a diferencia de Python 2.x donde `input` evalúa la cadena ingresada como si de código Python se tratara. Sospecho que intentas reproducir el comportamiento de Python 2 en Python 3, para más información mirate:

- [Diferencia entre input() y raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38288/diferencia-entre-input-y-raw-input)

Cuando ingresas la cadena `"L1"`, `input` simplemente la retorna como un objeto `str`, el `input` equivale a :

```
m1 = "L1"
```

Por lo tanto si ingresas `"L1"` y `"L2"` en los inputs la linea que marca el error queda en realidad:

```
media_nivel= ("L1"+"L2")/2
```

el operador  `+`  cuando los operandos son cadenas **concatena** ambas cadenas, por lo que al resolver el paréntesis queda:

```
media_nivel= "L1L2" / 2
```

Lógicamente no puedes dividir una cadena de texto entre un entero y por eso la excepción.

En Python 2.x el código funcionaría porque `input` como se comenta no retorna una cadena (eso lo hace `raw_input`), sino que evalúa lo  ingresado como código Python válido. AL ingresar `"L1"` evalúa la cadena y como `L1` es el nombre de una variable `m1` queda  asociado al mismo objeto que ésta, el entero `1`. En este caso el `input` equivaldría a:

```
m1 = L1
```

Puedes conseguir esto en Python 3.x con el homólogo de `input` en Python 2, `eval`:

```
L1 = 1
L2 = 2
L3 = 3

m1 = eval(input("Inserte nivel del primer miembro: "))    
m2 = eval(input("Inserte nivel del segundo miebro: "))

media_nivel= (m1 + m2) / 2

print(media_nivel)
```

Pero lo anterior por lo general **no debes hacerlo nunca a no ser que sea en aplicaciones muy específicas en las ** (creación de intérpretes/consolas interactivas o similares, programas que se ejecuten en un entorno muy controlado o personal, con la entrada saneada previamente, etc). Como `eval` evalúa toda cadena que se ingrese como código Python es peligrosa si se usa para procesar entradas de usuario sin saneamiento previo, dado que deja la puerta totalmente abierta a ataques de inyección de código como se explica en la pregunta enlazada antes. Por desgracia aún hay muchos ejemplos por ahí rondando haciendo uso de `input` para procesar entradas de usuario en Python 2 (en Python 3 es totalmente correcto), lo cual ha propagado esta muy mala práctica, muchas veces en desconocimiento de que hace la función realmente.

En tu caso, sanear la entrada es bastante simple, bastaría con algo así.

```
op_validas = {"L1", "L2", "L3"}
op = eval(input("Inserte nivel del primer miembro: "))   
if op not in op_validas:
    print("Nivel no válido")
    # Salir del programa o volver a pedir entrada
else:
    m1 = eval(op)
```

Pero no deja de ser complicarse sin necesidad, cuando existen opciones más legibles. La opción más simple y segura es usar algún contenedor para almacenar las variables, un diccionario es perfecto para ello:

```
niveles = {"L1": 1, "L2": 2, "L3": 3}

m1 = input("Inserte nivel del primer miembro: ")
m2 = input("Inserte nivel del segundo miebro: ")

media_nivel= (niveles[m1] + niveles[m2]) / 2

print(media_nivel)
```

Usar un diccionario hace que sea trivial crear nuevos "niveles" o actualizar el valor asociado en tiempo de ejecución de ser necesario, simplemente se trata de indizar usando la clave y asignar su valor:

```
niveles["L4"] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate así.

```
def niveles():
    L1=1
    L2=2
    L3=3

    # (m1 = MIEMBRO1)

    m1=input("Inserte nivel del primer miebro: ") #AQUI ESCRIBE UNO DE LOS VALORES L1, L2 O L3, y EL OUTPUT DEVUELVE 1, 2 O 3

    m2=input("Inserte nivel del segundo miebro: ") #AQUI ESCRIBE UNO DE LOS VALORES P1, P2 O P3, y EL OUTPUT DEVUELVE 1, 2 O 3

    if m1 = 'L1':
        m1 = L1
    elif m1 = 'L2':
        m1 = L2
    elif m1 = 'L3':
        m1 = L3
    else:
        print "Valor inválido: " + m1

    if m2 = 'P1':
        m2 = P1
    elif m2 = 'P2':
        m2 = P2
    elif m2 = 'P3':
        m2 = P3
    else:
        print "Valor inválido: " + m2

    try:
        media_nivel= (m1+m2)/2
        print(media_nivel)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```