# Como actualizar los datos de una elemento de una tabla con SQLalchemy en python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

me propuse a aprender algo de base de datos con python (antes había usado flask con sqlalchemy), la cosa es que quiero actualizar un elemento de la base de datos, con flask y sqlalchemy era simple solo actualizabas una clase y hacías el commit pero sin flask es mas complejo al parecer (no estoy seguro) se usa una función `update()` , En resumen busco saber como usar la funcion `update()` para editar el elemento, les dejo mi codigo

```
def AddProduc():
    producto = Producto()
    print ("\t\t .: Agregar Producto :. ")

    producto.product_id = raw_input("\t ID del producto ( codigo de barras ): ")
    Exist_Product = session.query( Producto ).filter_by( product_id = producto.product_id ).first()

    # AGREGAR O ACTUALIZAR 
    if Exist_Product == None:
        producto.nombre     = raw_input("\t Nombre del producto: ")
        producto.precio     = input("\t Precio del producto: ")
        producto.cantidad   = input("\t Cuantos productos va a agregar: ")
        session.add( producto )
        session.commit()
    else:
        Cantidad_Nuevo = input("\t Cuantos productos va a sumar: ")
        Cantidad_Nuevo = Cantidad_Nuevo + Exist_Product.cantidad
        # Lo que esta adentro de update() es el nombre de la tabla no la clase
        session.update( producto ).values( cantidad = Cantidad_Nuevo ).where()
```

La tabla esta declarada asi:

```
class Producto( db ):
    __tablename__ = "producto"

    product_id  = Column( Integer(),primary_key = True )
    precio      = Column( Integer())
    cantidad    = Column( Integer())
    nombre      = Column( String(50))
```

Gracias de antemano <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de actualizar el campo, por ejemplo:

- Modificar directamente el atributo del objeto:

  ```
  exist_product.cantidad = Producto.cantidad + cantidad_nuevo
  session.commit()
  ```
- [`sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#)

  ```
  (session.query(Producto)
          .filter_by(product_id=product_id)
          .update({"cantidad": Producto.cantidad + cantidad_nuevo})
          )
  session.commit(
  ```

  > Este método está pensado para consultas masivas y hay que tener en cuenta algunos peligros asociados a su uso. Ver documentación.)
- [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=table%20update#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.update) / [`sqlalchemy.schema.Table.update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=table%20update#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.update):

  ```
  from sqlalchemy import update


  stmt = (update(Producto)
              .where(Producto.product_id == product_id)
              .values(cantidad=Producto.cantidad + cantidad_nuevo)
               )
  session.execute(stmt)
  session.commit()
  ```

Ejemplo completo reproducible basado en el código de la pregunta y usando sqlite3:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import update


Base = declarative_base()


class Producto(Base):
    __tablename__ = "producto"

    product_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    precio = Column(Integer())
    cantidad = Column(Integer())
    nombre = Column(String(50))


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.sqlite')
session_maker = sessionmaker()
session_maker.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = session_maker()


def add_produc():
    print("\t\t .: Agregar Producto :. ")

    product_id = raw_input("\t ID del producto ( codigo de barras ): ")
    exist_product = (session.query(Producto)
                            .filter_by(product_id=product_id)
                            .first()
                     )

    # AGREGAR O ACTUALIZAR
    if exist_product is None:
        producto = Producto()
        producto.product_id = product_id
        producto.nombre = raw_input("\t Nombre del producto: ")
        producto.precio = int(raw_input("\t Precio del producto: "))
        producto.cantidad = int(raw_input("\t Cuantos productos va a agregar: "))
        session.add(producto)
        session.commit()

    else:
        cantidad_nuevo = int(raw_input("\t Cuantos productos va a sumar: "))
        exist_product.cantidad = Producto.cantidad + cantidad_nuevo
        session.commit()


add_produc()
```

Unas pequeñas observaciones:

- La forma correcta de saber si un objeto es `None` es usando el operador `is`, no el operador de igualdad:

  ```
  if exist_product == None:  # No
  if exist_product is None:  # Si
  ```
- Como norma general no uses `input` para entradas de usuario en Python 2, no es para ingresar valores numéricos. Usa `raw_input` y un casting explicito a `int`.

  - [Diferencia entre input() y raw_input()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089)
- Es buena idea que sigas las convenciones de estilo definidas en PEP 8 en lo posible. Los nombres de las variables, métodos y funciones deben ser en minúscula y usando `_` para separar palabras. Reservar CamelCase para las clases y todo en mayúsculas para las "constantes".

  - [Guía de estilo para código Python - PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> El código es para Python 2  que es el usado en la pregunta, pero basta con cambiar `raw_input` por `input` o establece un alias al inicio:
>
> ```
> raw_input = input
> ```
>
> para que pueda ser utilizado en Python 3.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario me ayudo mucho y también lo de las observaciones me ayudaron mucho, aunque me quedo una duda en la parte de `exist_product.cantidad = Producto.cantidad + cantidad_nuevo`, porque se usa  `Producto.cantidad`, y no `exist_product.cantidad` para sumarse a si mismo, Muchas gracias <3