# Debian-Python | NameError: name 'luis' is not defined

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi

Al ejecutar el programa python en debian me devuelve el siguiente error. ¿Que sucede?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "nombre3.py", line 1, in <module>
        nombre = input("Nombre: \n")
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'luis' is not defined
-----------------------------
(program exited with code 1)
Press return to continue
```

Programa python3.py

```
nombre = input("Nombre: \n")
print(nombre)
```

Ejecución de programa:

```
Nombre:
luis
```

Versión python 2.7.16
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python estás usando?

Comment: versión python 2.7.16

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de tu versión `Python`, en lugar de usar `input()` debes usar `raw_input()`.

```
nombre = raw_input("Nombre: \n")
print(nombre)
```

`raw_input()` ya no se usa en las versiones recientes de `Python` (versión > 3).

---

**Diferencias entre `input()` y `raw_input()` en Python 2.7:**

`raw_input()` =  *Si el argumento de solicitud está presente, se escribe en la salida estándar sin una nueva línea final. La función lee una línea desde la entrada, la convierte en una cadena (quitando una nueva línea final) y la devuelve.*

`input()` = *Evalúa una operación dada. Lo toma como código:*

Ejemplo:

```py
edad = input("Calculemos la edad \n")
print(edad)
```

> Calculemos la edad
>
> 2019-1998
>
> 21

[Fuente](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

[Respuesta en este sitio, que explica lo anterior más detalladamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38303/109169)