# Condición FOR para recorrer CSV en pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, bucle-for, condiciones

Estoy trabajando con el Modulo PANDAS y quiero ingresar un valor de la tabla .csv y quiero que me determine otro valor de la misma tabla, por ejemplo:

SI INGRESO EL DISTRITO = PEBAS QUIERO QUE ME RESPONDA LA ZONA SISMICA = 1, EN ESTE CASO 1, como se observa en la imagen.

Este es la parte del código, lo que me falta es recorrer la tabla con el bucle FOR y poner la condición IF para condicionar la entrada.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datos = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)

ingreso = str(input("Ingresa: "))
```

...

Tabla de datos:
[image: Tabla de datos a ingresar]

Comment: Si tu input siempre será *distrito*, puedes hacer `df[df[‘DISTRITO’]==tu_input] `

Comment: Gracias @LucasDamian, buen aporte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente no necesitas un ciclo for para ello (por norma general mucho más ineficiente que los métodos vectorizados que ofrece Pandas), pero puedes usarlo de varias formas además:

- Iterando sobre los índices:

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")

  ingreso = input("Ingresa: ")
  for idx in df.index:
      if df.DISTRITO[idx] == ingreso:
          print(f"La zona sísmica de '{ingreso}' es: {df.ZONASISMICA[idx]}")
          break # Rompemos el ciclo
  else:
      print(f"No se ha encontrado el distrito '{ingreso}'")
  ```
- Iterando sobre `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`:

  ```
  import pandas as pd


  df = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")

  ingreso = input("Ingresa: ")
  for _, row in df.iterrows():
      if row.DISTRITO == ingreso:
          print(f"La zona sísmica de '{ingreso}' es: {row.ZONASISMICA}")
          break # Rompemos el ciclo
  else:
      print(f"No se ha encontrado el distrito '{ingreso}'")
  ```
- Iterando sobre `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples`:

  ```
  import pandas as pd


  df = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")

  ingreso = input("Ingresa: ")
  for row in df.itertuples():
      if row.DISTRITO == ingreso:
          print(f"La zona sísmica de '{ingreso}' es: {row.ZONASISMICA}")
          break # Rompemos el ciclo
  else:
      print(f"No se ha encontrado el distrito '{ingreso}'")
  ```

Tienes otras opciones usando los métodos propios de Pandas/NumPy sien el uso de ciclos Python crudos:

- Usando un filtro boleano y `loc`:

  ```
  import pandas as pd


  df = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")

  ingreso = input("Ingresa: ")

  row = df[df.DISTRITO == ingreso].head(1)
  if not row.empty:
      print(f"La zona sísmica de '{ingreso}' es: {row.ZONASISMICA.iloc[0]}")
  else:
      print(f"No se ha encontrado el distrito '{ingreso}'")
  ```
- Usando `pandas.DataFrame.query:`

  ```
  import pandas as pd


  df = pd.read_csv("distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")

  ingreso = input("Ingresa: ")

  row = df.query(f"DISTRITO == '{ingreso}'").head(1)
  if not row.empty:
      print(f"La zona sísmica de '{ingreso}' es: {row.ZONASISMICA.iloc[0]}")
  else:
      print(f"No se ha encontrado el distrito '{ingreso}'")
  ```

Existen más posibilidades, estas son solo algunas de ellas.

Un par de observaciones:

- [`input` en Python 3.x retorna siempre una cadena](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38288/15089), por lo que el casting a `str` es innecesario y redundante.
- `pandas.read_csv` ya retorna un DataFrame, por lo que en principio no necesitas para nada hacer `df = pd.DataFrame(datos)`.