# Leer datos seguidos

Tags: python

quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de que Python me lea una linea y la separe en varios datos.
por ejemplo, tengo estos dos numeros en una misma linea 2606555999 2606556782, ¿python podria leerlos como numeros separados?

```
a = input()
b = input()

def sumalista(listaNumeros):
    laSuma=0
    for i in listaNumeros:
        laSuma = laSuma + i
    return laSuma

print("La suma entre " + str(a) + " y " + str(b) + " es " + str(sumalista(range(int(a), int(b) + int(1)))))
```

este es mi codigo, cuando leo los numeros anteriores recibo como error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sumaAB.py", line 1, in <module>
    a = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    2606555999 2606556782
                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Parece que estás usando Python2. En esa versión la función `input` evalua la expresión que ingresas. La que deberías usar es `raw_input`. Para una explicación más detallada, mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38288/diferencia-entre-input-y-raw-input/38303#38303).

Comment: Está usando python3, veo que el `print` se usa como función...

Answer (score 0):

Pimero debes obtener tu cadena de texto en este caso debe estar separada por espacios,
luego extraer cada numero y convertirlo a entero y con la funcion `sum()` puedes sumar tu arreglo

```
textoLargo = input()
c=[ int(num) for  num in textoLargo.split()]

print(sum(c))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]